# Algorithms-how to find a subset in weighted binary tree that maximises weight and no pair of nodes have parent-child relationship

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, dynamic-programming

So i am on my algorithms and complexity homework  and there is an exercise that's a pain. i have a binary tree with  weight labels(integers) on each node and an integer k and i have to find a subset of the nodes containing at most k nodes , that maximizes the sum of weights and no pair of nodes in the subset have parent-child relationship .  I am supposed to utilize dynamic programming to solve that .

So as a first notion i was thinking of checking the sum of  all the subsets with cardinality 2 ( that have the required property ) , and scale to cardinality k using the subproblems to construct the solution . i have problems all the way though .  Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dynamic programming solution:

1. The state is `(node, set_size, is_taken)`. The value is the maximum sum of a set such that all nodes in this set belong to a subtree rooted in a `node`, its size is `set_size` and `is_taken` indicates whether the `node` itself belongs to this set or not.
2. The base case is as follows: for all leaves, `f(leaf, 0, false) = 0`(it means that this leaf is not taken) and `f(leaf, 1, true) = the weight of this leaf` (it means that this leaf is taken).
3. We can compute the values of `f` for inner nodes in the following manner: first, we compute it for a node's children, and then we merge the results(either taking this node or not).
4. The answer is the maximum of `max(f(root, k', false), f(root, k', true))` among all `k' <= k`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is similar to the well-known maximum independent set problem.

Hint: You will have to construct a 2-D matrix where

```
DP[i][j] = Maximum node weight till node i taking at-most j nodes.
DP[i][j] ~ Max(DP[parent(i)][j], DP[grandparent(i)][j-1] + Wi)
```

Fill up the matrix by conducting a DFS on the tree starting from the root.

**Note:**
The above recurrence relation is just an idea to get you started. The exact relation shall have to be worked out taking into account the DFS and order of traversal of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can define it as

```
T(v, parent_chosen)
```

`T` is the maximum subset sum for the subtree rooted at `v` whether v's parent was chosen or not.

```
T(null, _) = 0

#if v's parent was chosen only check for children
T(v, true) = T(left(v), false)+T(right(v), false)   

#if v's parent wasn't chosen, try both options (choosing and not choosing)
T(v, false) = max(
    T(left(v), true)+T(right(v), true)+weight(v), 
    T(left(v), false)+T(right(v), false)
)
```

The solution is given by:

```
T(root, false)
```

This solution is O(n).